# JAXB basics and parsing xml

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have understood basics about JAXB. I tried one sample program and need some help.

1. I created a sample JAXB project and tried parsing one xsd and its xml file.. got error. Later I figured out that I need jdk i my targeted run-times as JAXB uses some extra files that are not in JRE. Can some explain more please?
2. then I have parsed the files.I haven't worked with xml's before so I am not sure what syntax is to be followed. I think my xml file should have some mentioning about xsd file. Is this correct? As I parsed in one of the classes I got this code generated:

   `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlType(name = "BookForm", propOrder = {
   "author",
   "title",
   "genre",
   "price",
   "pubDate",
   "review"
   })`

shouldn't these have datatypes in front of them?

My sample xsd is:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:books"
        xmlns:bks="urn:books">
<xsd:element name="books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>
<xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="book" 
              type="bks:BookForm" 
              minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
  <xsd:element name="pub_date" type="xsd:date" />
  <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

My sample xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:books">
<book id="bk001">
  <author>Writer</author>
  <title>The First Book</title>
  <genre>Fiction</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
  <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
</book></x:books>
```

where can I get more info about all these annotations and how does JAXB generates classes?

Comment: JAXB is defined by [JSR-222](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr222/index2.html), which has the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxb-2.2-mrel2a-oth-JSpec/), in case you want the detail. Probably better to start with [The Java™ Tutorials - Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). You can also read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html) of the annotations.

Comment: That's the only code generated? How did you generate (which command, and parameters) that?

Comment: No That's the a very short part of what code was generated...